# MySQL Read from Multiple Tables based on same ID

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have 14 tables that I need to read from at once. I read each table separately like:
Open Conn
Get all data where ID matches
Close conn.
Open Conn
Get all data that matches ID from main table
Close
etc..
I can't get the syntax correctly to read it all at once. Read times are getting too long.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM maindata" +
                        " WHERE idmaindata = "
                        + IDprovided;

while (rdr.Read()) // Store 25 variables to class
{
    readClass.Name = rdr.GetString(1);
...
}


sql = "SELECT * FROM tableforeman" +
       " WHERE tableforeman.id_maintable = "
        + IDprovided; // Same ID for all tables

while (rdr.Read()) // 2 variables - multiple entries (order doesn't matter)
{
    personDetails.Name = rdr.GetString(1);
    personDetails.Email = rdr.GetString(2);

 mainClass.foreman.Add(personDetails);
}




sql = "SELECT * FROM tableeng" +
        " WHERE tableeng.id_maintable = "
        + IDprovided; 

while (rdr.Read())
{

  personDetails.Name = rdr.GetString(1);
  personDetails.Email = rdr.GetString(2);

mainClass.eng.Add(personDetails);
}


sql = "SELECT * FROM tablesuper" +
     " WHERE tablecosuper.id_maintable = "
     + IDprovided; 
while (rdr.Read())
{
    personDetails.Name = rdr.GetString(1);
    ersonDetails.Email = rdr.GetString(2);
    mainClass.super.Add(personDetails);
}
     

           


sql = "SELECT * FROM tablecomponents" +
      " WHERE tablecomponents.id_maintable = "
      + id_maintable +
      " ORDER BY id_order";

while (rdr.Read()) // 14 variables
{
   ClassComponents component = new ClassComponents();
   ClassComponents = rdr.GetString(1);
   ClassComponents = rdr.GetString(2); ...

MainClass.ClassComponents.Add(ClassComponents);  / Multiple components. Grouped by id_order, hence adding to main class per read
}
```

.
.
.
9 more tables to read, most of them are order by id inside table. Is there a way I can do it all in one query? If so how do I store the variables then.

Thanks.

Comment: join the tables and so you have only one reader, but please read about **sql injection** and **prepared statements with parameters**

Comment: you could also write a stored procedure, and return them each as cursors.. That should be much lighter than 14 indevidual calls

Comment: You can write a store procedure and concentrate there all the queries, but also you can create a string query and pass the information there. Please, follow the advise of @nbk